# Tilde key on Mac Air with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, macbook

By default, no layout on my Macbook Air allows me to print backtick (`) and tilde (~) symbols. Instead, I get backslash, pipe or whatever, depending from the layout.

I changed the behavior of the key that I want to use to print tilde using the following commands:

```
xev
<press tilde button>
keycode <keycode from xev output> = grave asciitilde >~/.Xmodmap
xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc
```

(instructions are based on these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757232/switch-tab-and-backtick-keys-ubuntu-linux)

But unfortunately, after I switch the layout, I get the default behavior again.

How to make these changes permanent?

Comment: This is a problem I'm searching a *simple* solution for too. Just to add, the issue is that with Ubuntu 14.04 xmodmap is no longer functional. Its changes gets overwritten periodically (after a few minutes in my case) by xkb. I'm not an expert on this and still searching for a solution as well. This is just to inform you of the reason for this problem.

Comment: @BoazRymland I solved the problem myself, just forgot to report. You may find the solution below, hope it helps you as well.

Comment: thanks! I'll try it later. I don't like the idea of editing system file (or files that are suspected as such, with lack of knowing better) but I'm curious and want to resolve this. 
Thanks again!

Comment: I don't even have tilde button on my Macbook Finnish keyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem.

First off, `xmodmaprc` doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04. 
The solution is to edit `xkb` (X KeyBoard extension) config files.

Find the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`, backup it, then open and comment out the line:

```
key <LSGT> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };
```

And on the next line, add the following:

```
key <LSGT> { [ grave, asciitilde, grave, asciitilde ] };
```

If you need to change configuration for another locale, check the folder `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` and find the file corresponding to the locale you want to change.

To apply the changes, you have to remove all xkb cache files:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

Comment: works after a reboot. Works on ubuntu 16.04LTS as well as on elementaryOS

Comment: This is a more correct answer than @yasmar's as it corrects the system cofiguration rather than overriding it after it's applied.

Answer (score 22):

The solution that worked for Timofey did not work for me for some reason. However, a solution which did work was to put the line

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/iso_layout
```

into `/etc/rc.local`.

This suggestion comes from here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1245081

via

https://stdio.sangwhan.com/backtick-tilde-problem-macbook-air/

Comment: also works in 16.04

Comment: Also works on MacBook Pro

Comment: Works on Macbook Pro 12,1 w/ debian

Comment: This long-established solution inexplicably stopped working for me.  I'm no longer able to edit this file, and so placing the code into the `rc.local` has no effect.  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution which works as an unpriviledged user is:

```
setxkbmap -option apple:badmap
```

As a priviledged user this can also be used to fix the issue in the X config of the keyboard device with something like:

```
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-custom-kbd.conf
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"

    Option "XKbOptions" "apple:badmap"
EndSection
```

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for me.  This one did. I'm on a MBP late 2015 with US keyboard fixing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running with Parallels Desktop 17.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 with a Mac keyboard you should be able to get a tilde symbol by pressing Right Alt + ] key.

Comment: Wow, I found it on a French Apple keyboard where you normally press Alt + N on OSX. I don't have any ], but it worked with *Right* Alt + N (but not Left Alt + N!)