# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't handle Macbook keyboard

Tags: keyboard, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook Pro yesterday and today I noticed that the key right below ESC isn't correct.  Where it should produce ` and ~ (which it does under OS X), it produces < and >.  I haven't tested the whole keyboard, so I don't know if there are others.  Is there a way to fix that without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: You probably just have the wrong keyboard layout selected. Go to System Settings -> Text Entry and see what input sources are there. Click the plus sign to add an input method, if necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tilde key on Mac Air with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530325/tilde-key-on-mac-air-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix that worked for my MacBookPro 12,1 (Retina) on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS "xenial" running kernel 4.8.0-51 generic

Back up before editing:

```
nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

Comment out

```
key <LSGT> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };
```

and add

```
key <LSGT> { [ grave, asciitilde, grave, asciitilde ] };
```

Apply the change

```
rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

Logout/login.

Thanks to [Timofey](https://askubuntu.com/users/199973/timofey) ([source here](https://askubuntu.com/a/553174))

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 with a Mac keyboard you should be able to get a tilde symbol by pressing <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> key.