# keyboard one button shows wrong character

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have been using Turkish layout on ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook. When I use command character(left of number 1), it shows less than operator symbol(<). (In the picture, the left green ones) How can be the problem fixed? The all other buttons work well. I think the button may be edited by `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` but I'm not sure. Similar problem I have just realized: [Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't handle Macbook keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840149/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-handle-macbook-keyboard)

[image]

[image]
shifted keys:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

IMO, it is a really trivial solution because the issue is deeper. Having determined that which are greater,less, eacute, grave,  I have exchanged them from the keyboard layout C file(`tr` for me) on `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. 
[image]